# Which files to version control in mplabx nbproject directory?

Tags: mplabx

I just discovered the files in the directory `nbproject` are required for MPLABX to realize a .X directory is a project.  I don't want my teammates to continually struggle with having to update every single time I make a small change, like recompile.  What are the minimum files I should I add to my version control system?

Screenshot of what I think are too many files to manage a project:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be purely a software question, maybe best asked at stackoverflow. What is the recommendation at microchip?

Comment: Some information from Microchip on the files and directories is here: http://microchip.wikidot.com/mplabx:directory-structure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use Mercurial for our embedded projects at the office, including MPLAB X. I came up with the following guidelines for the team when Mercurializing MPLAB X projects:

- Version all of the source files in the project root directory (duh)
- Version the Makefile in the project root directory
- Inside *\nbproject*, version the following:

  - configurations.xml
  - project.properties
  - project.xml
- Inside *\nbproject\private*, version everything:

  - configurations.xml
  - private.properties
  - private.xml

This works well for us where we have varying operating systems and varying versions of MPLAB X. Cloning the repo and opening it works, MPLAB X will recreate the missing files and away you go. The only nuisance will be having to select your own programmer/debugger in project config, but there's no avoiding that - MPLAB X tracks the tools by serial number.

Before starting all this, we also figured out that we need the compilers to be installed in a common location (C:\Microchip\MPLABXC16\vX.XX, C:\Microchip\MPLABXC32\vX.XX, etc.) because depending on 32-bit or 64-bit O/S they end up in \Program Files or \Program Files (x86) which was problematic. I don't think this is still necessary with the above versioning scheme - YMMV.

Comment: Thanks Adam - I created a [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file based on this which is at: https://github.com/edeca/Electronics/blob/master/Support/gitignore.txt

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Answer (score 5):

From http://microchip.wikidot.com/faq:72

Which files in an MPLAB® X Project should be under version control?

The following table lists project files that either need or do not need to be committed to a version control repository.

**Directory or File(s)  Commit?**

**Project Directory**

*Makefile* Yes

*Source files*           Yes

***build directory***            No

***dist directory***             No

**nbproject directory**

*configurations.xml*         Yes

*project.properties*         Yes

*project.xml*                Yes

*Makefile-* *                No

*Package-* *                 No

***private directory***      No

Yes: Required to generate the project image.
No: These directories/files are regenerated and therefore do not need to be saved.

Comment: this is the correct and official answer